# Shorthand CASE with additional conditions

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Up until today I held as true the notion that shorthand CASE doesn't accept additional conditions, as in

```
CASE evaluate_this
WHEN TRUE AND another_field ... THEN ...
```

would never work.

Today, as I was distractingly writing some code, I violated this rule just to realise that one `CASE` expression still worked as intended, the other didn't.
Assuming the following data:

| id | boolean_one | boolean_two | field_one | field_two |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | TRUE | TRUE | NULL | 'a' |
| 2 | TRUE | FALSE | 2 | 'a' |
| 3 | FALSE | TRUE | 8 | NULL |
| 4 | FALSE | FALSE | NULL | NULL |

The one that did not work looked like this:

```
CASE boolean_one
  WHEN TRUE AND field_one IS NOT NULL THEN field_one * UNIFORM(1, 10, RANDOM())
  ELSE field_one
END AS new_field_one
```

The idea is that in most circumstances the value for `new_field_one` should match `field_one`, the only exception being when `boolean_one = TRUE AND field_one IS NOT NULL` in which case it should be assigned the product of field_one and a random integer.

Below the desired and actual values for `new_field_one` based on the above

| id | desired | actual |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | NULL | NULL |
| 2 | 20 | 20 |
| 3 | 8 | 8 |
| 4 | NULL | 5 |

So it applies the randomisation also when `boolean_one = FALSE AND field_one IS NULL`.
Fixing the expression to

```
CASE
  WHEN boolean_one = TRUE AND field_one IS NOT NULL THEN...
```

solves the issue. What I find more interesting, and confusing, is that the second expression still did what it was meant to do:

```
CASE boolean_two
  WHEN TRUE AND field_two = 'b' THEN 'a'
  WHEN TRUE AND field_two = 'a' THEN 'b'
  ELSE field_two
END AS new_field_two
```

which in this case means that `new_field_two = 'b'` for the row with `ID = 1`, and all other remain equal to field_two.

So, this doesn't seem to be an issue of adding an extra condition to a shorthand `CASE` per se, I would guess it must have something to do specifically with the fact that the second condition is a NULL check. Am I on the right track?

Comment: It's evaluated as an expression before the comparison. `TRUE AND X` reduces to just `X` so the behavior is driven only by whether or not your second column is null.

Comment: Desired output for row 2 should be 2 rather than 20.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the shortcut syntax the "when expression" is evaluated as a whole and then that value is compared against the "case expression". It's not matching the value as true and then running an extra check

In fact your `true and` is essentially ignored because `true and X` is just equivalent to `X` in Boolean logic. The test then is whether `boolean_one` matches the non-null state of `field_one`. The second and fourth rows correspond to `true = true` and `false = false` which is when you're seeing the random result values.

You could certainly nest `case` if there were a real benefit to legibility:

```
case boolean_one
    when true then
        case field_one is not null ... end
    else field_one
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Shawnt00 answer is good,

I like to think of the two forms as

chained If expression

```
CASE
   WHEN check1 THEN r1
   WHEN check2 THEN r2
   WHEN check3 THEN r3
END
```

if the same as

```
IF(check1) 
   r1
ELSE IF (check2)
   r2
...
```

where-as this "shortcut" version is the Switch statement form:

```
CASE expression
   WHEN val1 THEN r1
   WHEN val2 THEN r2
   WHEN val3 THEN r2
END
```

is the same as

```
SWITCH(expression){
    CASE val1: r1
    CASE val2: r2
    CASE val3: r3
}
```

which is to say the VAL things need to evaluate down, thus for you stumbled upon cases, you are writing extra boolean logic, which resolves down to a boolean answer. And as the [doc's note](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/case.html#arguments), for a `expression` to match a `value` they need to be of the same type of can be auto converted.

thus this gives a SQL error:

```
select 
    case false
    when true then 1
    when 'bob' then 2
end;
```

> Boolean value 'bob' is not recognized

because the second value cannot be auto converted to the same type as the case expression, which is a boolean value.